# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on mac

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems

Im trying to install a gem but keep running into the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mandrill-template-manager:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170221-17481-1m13rrx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
make "DESTDIR="
make: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/universal-darwin16/ruby/config.h', needed by `unicode.o'.  Stop.

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/unicode-0.4.4.2/gem_make.out
```

I have tried the following:

- adjusting the sources file with http
- downgrading ruby

UPDATE: RAN xcode-select --install

RESULT;

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mandrill-template-manager:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170221-18173-nchdps.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2/ext/unicode
make "DESTDIR="
compiling unicode.c
In file included from unicode.c:13:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:68:
/usr/include/stdio.h:133:19: error: expected ')'
        int     (* _Nullable _close)(void *);
                             ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:133:6: note: to match this '('
        int     (* _Nullable _close)(void *);
                ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:134:19: error: expected ')'
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
                             ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:134:6: note: to match this '('
        int     (* _Nullable _read) (void *, char *, int);
               ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [unicode.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/unicode-0.4.4.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-16/2.0.0/unicode-0.4.4.2/gem_make.out
```

Too many errors but u get the picture ;)

Comment: What happens when you do `xcode-select --install` and then try again?

Comment: Running the command as we speak, look at question it fixed one error got me 20 more ...

Comment: The problem seems to be with the installation of the `unicode-0.4.4.2` gem. [Here is an issue related to your problem](https://github.com/inukshuk/jekyll-scholar/issues/171#issuecomment-253515270) From the issue: "I realized this was an issue with the compilers etc bundled with XCode. Poking around a bit, I found that updating to macOS Sierra somehow messed up XCode in general. Updating XCode 8 fixed everything. So this is now resolved! It was some funky issue with XCode upon updating to macOS Sierra, not jekyll-scholar."

Comment: Thanks, seems fixed now also had to install gem here /usr/local/bin cause no permissions in new osx.